# SQL find average time difference between rows for a given category

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, group-by

I browsed SO but could not quite find the exact answer or maybe it was for a different language.

Let's say I have a table, where each row is a record of a trade:

```
trade_id customer trade_date
1        A        2013-05-01 00:00:00
2        B        2013-05-01 10:00:00    
3        A        2013-05-02 00:00:00
4        A        2013-05-05 00:00:00
5        B        2013-05-06 12:00:00
```

I would like to have the average time between trades, in days or fraction of days, *for each* customer, and the number of days since last trade. So for instance for customer A, time between trades 1 and 3 is 1 day and between trades 3 and 4 is 3 days, for an average of 2. So the end table would look like something like this (assuming today it's the 2013-05-10):

```
customer avg_time_btw_trades time_since_last_trade
A        2.0                 5.0
B        5.08                3.5
```

If a customer has only got 1 trade I guess NULL is fine as output.

Not even sure SQL is the best way to do this (I am working with SQL server), but any help is appreciated!

Comment: @RolandStarke `(numberOfTrades - 1)`.  Then `- 1` is pretty important, and also means you end up wanting something like `NULLIF(numberOfTrades, 1) - 1` to avoid divide by zero errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  customer,
  DATEDIFF(second, MIN(trade_date), MAX(trade_date)) / (NULLIF(COUNT(*), 1) - 1) / 86400.0,
  DATEDIFF(second, MAX(trade_date), GETDATE()      )                             / 86400.0
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  customer
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eb46e/7

***EDIT:*** Added final field that I didn't notice, apologies.

Comment: Can you check on this question as well :)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48078869/perform-operations-on-dynamic-columns-from-pivot

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL script uses your data and gives the expected results.

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(   trade_id INT,
    customer CHAR(1),
    trade_date DATETIME );
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (1, 'A', '20130501');
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (2, 'B', '20130501 10:00');
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (3, 'A', '20130502');
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (4, 'A', '20130505');
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (5, 'B', '20130506 12:00');

DECLARE @getdate DATETIME
-- SET @getdate = getdate();
SET @getdate = '20130510';

SELECT s.customer
    , AVG(s.days_btw_trades) AS avg_time_between_trades
    , CAST(DATEDIFF(hour, MAX(s.trade_date), @getdate) AS float) 
        / 24.0 AS time_since_last_trade
FROM (
    SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(HOUR, t2.trade_date, t.trade_date) AS float) 
            / 24.0 AS days_btw_trades
        , t.customer
        , t.trade_date
    FROM @temp t
        LEFT JOIN @temp t2 ON t2.customer = t.customer
            AND t2.trade_date = (   SELECT MAX(t3.trade_date)
                                    FROM @temp t3
                                    WHERE t3.customer = t.customer
                                        AND t3.trade_date < t.trade_date)

    ) s
GROUP BY s.customer
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a date difference between every trade and average them.

```
select 
a.customer
,avg(datediff(a.trade_date, b.trade_date))
,datediff(now(),max(a.trade_date))
from yourTable a, yourTable b
where a.customer = b.customer
and b.trade_date = (
    select max(trade_date) 
    from yourTable c 
    where c.customer = a.customer 
    and a.trade_date > c.trade_date)
    #gets the one earlier date for every trade
group by a.customer
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for grins I added a solution that would use CTE's.  You could probably use a temp table if the first query is too large.  I used @MatBailie creation script for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE customer_trades (
  id            INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  customer_id   INT,
  trade_date    DATETIME,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  INDEX ix_user_trades (customer_id, trade_date)
)

INSERT INTO
  customer_trades (
    customer_id,
    trade_date
  )
VALUES
  (1, '2013-05-01 00:00:00'),
  (2, '2013-05-01 10:00:00'),
  (1, '2013-05-02 00:00:00'),
  (1, '2013-05-05 00:00:00'),
  (2, '2013-05-06 12:00:00')
;

;WITH CTE as(
select customer_id, trade_date, datediff(hour,trade_date,ISNULL(LEAD(trade_date,1) over (partition by  customer_id order by trade_date),GETDATE())) Trade_diff
from customer_trades
)
, CTE2 as
(SELECT customer_id, trade_diff, LAST_VALUE(trade_diff) OVER(Partition by customer_id order by trade_date) Curr_Trade from CTE)

SELECT Customer_id, AVG(trade_diff) AV, Max(Curr_Trade) Curr_Trade
FROM CTE2
GROUP BY customer_id
```