# Perform Operations on Dynamic Columns from Pivot

Tags: sql-server, pivot, dynamic-sql, dynamic-columns

As The Question says that I'm Trying to insert some values from dynamic sql Query to TempTable using Pivot, so the `ExistingCoulmnName` are not known to me

In the next step I want to perform some arithmatic operation lets say multipliation on those Column Values.

How Can I do that?

Attaching Some samples :

```
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(FYYear) 
                from #TempCapEx
                group by FYYear
                order by FYYear
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'') 

set @query = 'SELECT CapitalExpenditureId,' + @cols + ' into  
         ##GlobalTempForCapExPivotResult from 
         (
            select CapitalExpenditureId, FYYear, indicatorvalue
            from #TempCapEx
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            sum(indicatorvalue)
            for FYYear in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p'

execute (@query ) ;
```

So I have a `##GlobalTempForCapExPivotResult` as :

```
CapitalExpenditureId    2016-2017   2017-2018   2018-2019   2019-2020   2020-2021   2021-2022   2022-2023
22150                   0.0000      35200.0000  35200.0000  35200.0000  35200.0000  35200.0000  NULL
32632                   NULL        213695.0000 224379.0000 235599.0000 247379.0000 259748.0000 0.0000
1589                    10252.0000  170370.0000 0.0000      0.0000      0.0000      0.0000      NULL
14988                   0.0000      133000.0000 0.0000      0.0000      0.0000      0.0000      NULL
36877                   NULL        303.0300    404.040     101.010     0.0000      0.0000      0.0000
```

So the Financial Year Columns may increase or decrease, so how can I do somthing like this :

`Select [ExistingCoulmnName] * 3.5 from #GlobalTempForCapExPivotResult where [ExistingCoulmnName] = '[2016-2017]'`

Expected Output:

```
CapitalExpenditureId    2016-2017   2017-2018        2018-2019          2019-2020         2020-2021        2021-2022        2022-2023
22150                   0.00 * 3.5  35200.0000 * 3.5 35200.0000 * 3.5  35200.0000 * 3.5  35200.0000 * 3.5 35200.0000 * 3.5  NULL * 3.5
```

Comment: Do you just want that One column, or the existing columns, plus the one new column?  Do you want that column adding to the temp table, or as a separate query after having created the temp table?  I also presume you are passing in a parameter/variable with the value `'2016-2017'`?  *(Show the exact output that you want.)*

Comment: @MatBailie
Do you just want that One column, or the existing columns, plus the one new column? `Existing Columns`
Do you want that column adding to the temp table, or as a separate query after having created the temp table? `Separate Query`
I also presume you are passing in a parameter/variable with the value '2016-2017'? `Yes`

Comment: Please don't just reply in comments, update your question to clarify the scenario for all readers.  *(Not everyone will read all the comments.)*  Please also give a full example; you've given sample input data, do give sample expected results.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native way to do that inside a standard SQL statement.  Instead you use some language *(possibly even T-SQL)* to write a new query in to a string, and then execute that new query.  Much the same as your example already does.

```
DECLARE @field NVARCHAR(256) = N'2015-2016';

DECLARE @dynamicSelect NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @dynamicSelect = N'SELECT *, 3.5 * [' + @field + N'] AS new_field FROM ##GlobalTempForCapExPivotResult';

EXECUTE(@dynamicSelect);
```

Also, note that this type of problem is ***WHY*** you shouldn't make that global temporary table in the first place.  Normalised data structures are much friendlier to SQL.  Do the formatting ***outside*** of SQL.

This is your query without the global temporary table...

```
SELECT
  CapitalExpenditureId,
  FYYear,
  indicatorvalue * 3.5
FROM
  #TempCapEx
GROUP BY
  CapitalExpenditureId,
  FYYear
ORDER BY
  CapitalExpenditureId,
  FYYear
```

***You*** as a human being might prefer the flat file *(excel style)* table, but it is a really bad idea to make that type of table for use inside SQL.  Stick to normalised data structures, and learn how to use them.  Don't try to break SQL.

Comment: What if I want to imply this to all columns and all rows?

Comment: You do exactly what you already did in your example query to make the Global Temporary Table in the first place.  You loop through all the fields that you want to include, and build them in to your new `@dynamicSelect` and execute it...

Comment: that will the 4th dynamicSql in the query will it affect the performace ?

Comment: It's hardly any different from writing a SQL Query in C# or javascript or PHP, then executing the query.  It's not free, but it's not expensive...

Comment: one more thing like in my case when values are not their it returns null can i set it as 0 in case of null?

Comment: `COALESCE(<some-field>, <default-value>)` will replace all `NULL` occurrences of `<some-field>` with `<default-value>`.

Comment: About the updated ans actually the value is in multi currency (3.5) so it has to be done as per the request currency type to specific or vice -versa

Comment: This is turning in to a Q&A to teach SQL.  Sorry, but that's not what SO is for.  I recommend taking some tutorials on SQL, then asking specific questions as separate questions.

Comment: SO I will have to perform similar join in multiple places to avoid that I was trying to do like this

Comment: I recommend asking a new question.  But instead of "how do I implement this solution", try asking "how do I solve this problem"?  Give example starting data, the rules you need to implement and the example expected results.  This question can be paraphrased as "Having reached this problematic position, how do I proceed" and the best answer should be "Don't, you should go back and do the first steps differently".

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a dynamic UPDATE statement:

```
DECLARE
    @UPDATEList NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''
    , @DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'UPDATE ##GlobalTempForCapExPivotResult
SET ';

SELECT @UPDATEList += N'
    , '
    + QUOTENAME(FYYear) + N' = ' + QUOTENAME(FYYear) + N' * 3.5'
FROM #TempCapEx
GROUP BY FYYear;

SELECT @UPDATEList = SUBSTRING(@UPDATEList, 6, LEN(@UPDATEList) - 5);
SELECT @DynamicSQL += @UPDATEList + ';';

EXEC (@DynamicSQL);
```

that updates the global temp table.